# Simple Insert Variable PHP into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, variables, insert

I have a simple bit of code that I can't get working.

```
<?php
$mysqli_connection = new MySQLi('localhost', 'root', 'secret', 'edgeserver');
if ($mysqli_connection->connect_error) {
   echo "Not connected, error: " . $mysqli_connection->connect_error;

   $username = 'Eddie';
   $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
   $email = 'eddie_the_eagle@hotmail.com';
   $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);

   $sql = "INSERT INTO  `users` (`username`, `email`) 
           VALUES ( '".$username."', '".$email."')";
   $res = $mysqli_connection->query($sql);
}

?>
```

When I run the code no error appears but the users table remains empty.

Comment: `no error appears ` cause you don't check for one

Comment: @Dobro try answer. and mark one which is more descriptive and useful for you. vote-up others if possible and if they are useful too.

Comment: Did you try that code???

Comment: @Dobro please up-vote the answer also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems:-

1. you are mixing `mysql_*` with `mysqli_*`
2. no error checking is done.

Try like this:-

```
<?php

    $mysqli_connection = new MySQLi('localhost', 'root', 'secret', 'edgeserver');
    if ($mysqli_connection->connect_error)
    {
        echo "Not connected, error: " . $mysqli_connection->connect_error;
    }//Change
    $username = 'Eddie';
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_connection,$username);//connection link must be provided as a first parameter
    $email = 'eddie_the_eagle@hotmail.com';
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_connection,$email); //same here

    $sql = "INSERT INTO  users (username, email) VALUES ( '".$username."', '".$email."')";

    $res = $mysqli_connection->query($sql);
?>
```

**Note:-Please habitat yourselves to use error reporting when you are going to do any stuff. thanks.**

Answer (score 1):

> You were mixing two API's **mysql** and **mysqli**. Stop using deprecated **mysql**

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_connection,$username);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_connection,$email);
```

And you forgot to close your `if` condition too

```
if ($mysqli_connection->connect_error) {
    echo "Not connected, error: " . $mysqli_connection->connect_error;
}//<------forgot
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<?php

    $mysqli_connection = new MySQLi('localhost', 'root', 'secret', 'edgeserver');
    if ($mysqli_connection->connect_error)
    {
        echo "Not connected, error: " . $mysqli_connection->connect_error;
    }//Change
    $username = 'Eddie';
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_connection,$username);//Change
    $email = 'eddie_the_eagle@hotmail.com';
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_connection,$email); //Change

    $sql = "INSERT INTO  users (username, email) VALUES ( '".$username."', '".$email."')";

    $res = $mysqli_connection->query($sql);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close your if statement, so your insert logic will only run if there is an connect error.
Move the last `}` to a new line after

```
$mysqli_connection->connect_error;
```